# Replenish event sourced aggregate with kafka as event store

Tags: apache-kafka, cqrs, event-sourcing

More and more articles talk about kafka as an event store and using it in an application built with cqrs & event sourcing.
How do you query kafka (as the event store) for the events of a certain aggregate in order to complete an operation on the write side?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kafka Streams (http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/index.html) to compute aggregate of data stored in Kafka. In the next release (the vote is already ongoing) Kafka Streams adds a new feature called *Interactive Queries* that allows you to query the current value of each aggregate any time you want.

See the design document for now (still with the features old name "Queryable State") https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-67%3A+Queryable+state+for+Kafka+Streams

After the release there will be detailed documentation about how Interactive Queries work. If you have follow up question right now, just go ahead.

Comment: Is there any example on how to use kafka and queryable state? Should all events be on the same topic? One aggregate can have multiple types of events and I have the assumption that each event will have its own topic.

Comment: Is there any example on how to use kafka and queryable state? Should all events be on the same topic? One aggregate can have multiple types of events and I have the assumption that each event will have its own topic. And to query the state of a certain aggregate, we need to aggregate the results of all these events in order. Am I using Kafka in the wrong way?

Comment: Here are two examples: https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/blob/master/kafka-streams/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/interactivequeries/WordCountInteractiveQueriesExample.java and https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/blob/master/kafka-streams/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/interactivequeries/kafkamusic/KafkaMusicExample.java
(This repo contains other Kafka Streams examples, too).

Comment: A state is for a single operator. If you have different types, you can still create you own composite type to feed all you data to the same operator. The same is true for topic. For Kafka, the data is bytes only -- thus, if you provide a custom de/serializer, you can write different type into a single topic, too. (Not exactly sure what you mean to the second part of you question. Maybe you want to follow up on the Confluent or Kafka mailing list? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/confluent-platform or http://kafka.apache.org/contact)